scapy 255.255.255.255 broadcast not being received
I am trying to run some broadcast related tests in my network. I have a wireless client 10.48.225.30 and a wired host on the same subnet 10.48.225.45. I have a simple scapy script to run some broadcast traffic.
I have Wireshark running on both hosts. When I send out a 10.48.225.255 broadcast, the broadcast is seen by the other host, but when I send out 255.255.255.255 from either host, the other cannot see it. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on? The AP the wireless client is connected to and the wired host are on the same switch.
from scapy.all import *

#ip_layer = IP(dst="10.48.225.255")
ip_layer = IP(dst="255.255.255.255", src="10.48.225.30")
icmp_layer = ICMP(seq=9999)
packet = ip_layer / icmp_layer

for x in range(10):
   send(packet, iface="Wi-Fi")
   x = x + 1


most likely you sent those packets with a wrong dest mac addr, so that it's ignored (or not received) by a client

Shouldn't 255.255.255.255 be receivable by all hosts on the subnet?

Should be receivable if addressed correctly by underlying layer (it's not your case judging from the question), and should be ignorable (or not) by a receiver depending on its stack settings (it's also not your case yet)
